# Create new column by comparing existing column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, join

I have the following DataFrame:

```
   datetime            day_fetched         col_a col_b 
0  2023-01-02 12:00:00 2023-01-01 12:00:00 100  200  
1  2023-01-02 12:00:00 2023-01-02 12:00:00 120  400  
2  2023-01-03 12:00:00 2023-01-02 12:00:00 140  500  
3  2023-01-03 12:00:00 2023-01-03 12:00:00 160  700 
4  2023-01-04 12:00:00 2023-01-03 12:00:00 200  300 
5  2023-01-04 12:00:00 2023-01-04 12:00:00 430  200
```

And I want to create a new column that will take the value 2 if there is a difference in the date between `datetime` and `day_fetched` and value 1 if there is no difference.

So my new Dataframe should look like this:

```
   datetime            day_fetched         col_a col_b day_ahead
0  2023-01-02 12:00:00 2023-01-01 12:00:00 100  200    2
1  2023-01-02 12:00:00 2023-01-02 12:00:00 120  400    1
2  2023-01-03 12:00:00 2023-01-02 12:00:00 140  500    2
3  2023-01-03 12:00:00 2023-01-03 12:00:00 160  700    1
4  2023-01-04 12:00:00 2023-01-03 12:00:00 200  300    2
5  2023-01-04 12:00:00 2023-01-04 12:00:00 430  200    1
```

Then based on the column['`day_ahead`'], I want to split the `col_a` and `col_b`, into `col_a_1` and `col_a_2` and `col_b_1` and `col_b_2`.

So the final DataFrame will look like this:

```
   datetime            day_fetched         col_a_1 col_a_2 col_b_1 col_b_2 day_ahead
0  2023-01-02 12:00:00 2023-01-01 12:00:00 NaN     200     NaN     200     2
1  2023-01-02 12:00:00 2023-01-02 12:00:00 120     NaN     100     NaN     1
2  2023-01-03 12:00:00 2023-01-02 12:00:00 NaN     500     NaN     200     2
3  2023-01-03 12:00:00 2023-01-03 12:00:00 160     NaN     100     NaN     1
4  2023-01-04 12:00:00 2023-01-03 12:00:00 NaN     300     NaN     200     2
5  2023-01-04 12:00:00 2023-01-04 12:00:00 430     NaN     100     NaN     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `np.where`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data=
[["2023-01-02 12:00:00", "2023-01-01 12:00:00", 100,  200],
["2023-01-02 12:00:00", "2023-01-02 12:00:00", 120,  400],
["2023-01-03 12:00:00", "2023-01-02 12:00:00", 140,  500],
["2023-01-03 12:00:00", "2023-01-03 12:00:00", 160,  700],
["2023-01-04 12:00:00", "2023-01-03 12:00:00", 200,  300],
["2023-01-04 12:00:00", "2023-01-04 12:00:00", 430,  200]],
columns=["datetime","day_fetched","col_a","col_b"])

# days ahead
df["day_ahead"] = np.where(df["datetime"] == df["day_fetched"], 1, 2)
# column of None's for next section
df["na"] = None
# overwrite dataframe with new df
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.where(df["day_ahead"] == 1,
                                [df["datetime"], df["day_fetched"],
                                 df["col_a"], df["na"],
                                 df["col_b"], df["na"],
                                 df["day_ahead"]],
                                [df["datetime"], df["day_fetched"],
                                 df["na"], df["col_a"],
                                 df["na"], df["col_b"],
                                 df["day_ahead"]]).T,
                  columns=["datetime", "day_fetched",
                           "col_a_1", "col_a_2",
                           "col_b_1", "col_b_2",
                           "day_ahead"])

df
#               datetime          day_fetched col_a_1  ... col_b_1 col_b_2 day_ahead
# 0  2023-01-02 12:00:00  2023-01-01 12:00:00    None  ...    None     200         2
# 1  2023-01-02 12:00:00  2023-01-02 12:00:00     120  ...     400    None         1
# 2  2023-01-03 12:00:00  2023-01-02 12:00:00    None  ...    None     500         2
# 3  2023-01-03 12:00:00  2023-01-03 12:00:00     160  ...     700    None         1
# 4  2023-01-04 12:00:00  2023-01-03 12:00:00    None  ...    None     300         2
# 5  2023-01-04 12:00:00  2023-01-04 12:00:00     430  ...     200    None         1

# [6 rows x 7 columns]
```

When asking a question please provide data that can be easily copied, such as by using `df.to_dict()`.

### EDIT - Generalised for many columns

Here is a (more complicated) bit of code that uses a list comprehension to pivot based on the value of `day_ahead` for each `col_` and concatenates these to produce the same result:

```py
df = pd.concat(
    [df.pivot_table(index=[df.index, "datetime", "day_fetched"],
                    columns=["day_ahead"],
                    values=x).add_prefix(x+"_") for x in \
     df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith("col_")]] + \
        [df.set_index([df.index, "datetime", "day_fetched"])["day_ahead"]],
        axis=1).reset_index(level=[1, 2])
```

The second, third and fourth lines above create the pivot table and adds the column name and `"_"` as a prefix, and this is a list comprehension for each column in `df` that starts with `"col_"` (fifth line).  The sixth and seventh lines add the `day_ahead` column at the end of the DataFrame.  The eighth line resets the index so that `datetime` and `day_fetched` are columns.

Comment: thanks! I was wondering whether there is another way to do it using list comprehension, in case I have for example 10 columns instead of 2.

Comment: I have edited the answer to provide a generalised (and quite different) answer.

Comment: Note that you still need the `day_ahead` column code with this edit.